# Tablayout problem with keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, tabs

I've a Tablayout in my application. In one of the tablayout there is a listview with a search. When I want to write something in  the search the tablayout is visible and the layout. But I only want to show the keyboard and not the tablayout when I write something in the search box. When I close the keyboard the tablayout should display again.

Thanks for Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you see the tab widget under the keyboard, right?
To change this behavior add the following to your manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".CustomTabActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

in this case the tab widget doesn't change its location and the keyboard covers it.